# power analysis with different sample distributions

Tags: statistical-power, skewness

I need to perform a (two-sample) power analysis, however my data are differently distributed in both samples and I am not sure whether I can a standard approach through t-test.

Please see the distribution of a variable ('scale') in two samples:

[image]

and the data:

```
scale   scale
0   8   214.0
1   8   230.0
2   9   246.0
3   13  284.0
4   14  469.0
5   16  506.0
6   25  551.0
7   29  585.0
8   62  593.0
9   63  751.0
10  71  753.0
11  71  784.0
12  91  789.0
13  97  868.0
14  134 881.0
15  160 964.0
16  256 1089.0
17  258 1313.0
18  259 NaN
19  344 NaN
20  381 NaN
21  477 NaN
22  479 NaN
23  653 NaN
24  858 NaN
```

Where

- mu_1 = 194
- mu_2 = 660
- pooled_std = 350

and based on these figures, to achieve a power of 80% and a level of significance of 5% (two sided), for detecting a true difference in variable 'scale' means between the two groups, I need only **9** samples. So it seems like, based on these calculations and the sample size and the distribution of the variable scale.

However, obviously, that the distributions are skewed/not equal and a bit far from 't'.

Can I still use this approach? If not, please advise.

**UPDATE**

To put a bit of context into the numbers.  For example, consider a case where you would like to measure a glucose level ('scale') in people with diabetes and without (disease/healthy) and this is what you find (the table in above, higher values of glucose associated with a disease).

Then, based on the data, you decide to introduce a new screening tool with a certain threshold. If a new observation will be above (below) your threshold, than it will be suggested as a (not) disease.

My question is: based on the data distribution (see pics in above) and clearly obvious difference in means of both groups, can I say the I have enough power in this study?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what you need a power analysis for?  The differences between the two datasets are large and seemingly obvious.  Are these data actually paired, as suggested by your presentation of them?  If so, what do the "NaN" values mean?  These are much more important issues to address than any question of power.

Comment: This is what I was asked by a reviewer ('underpowered study') and I wanted to demonstrate that the difference is indeed significant, despite the fact there are only few samples. These are NOT paired observations, but rather measurements of a certain variable 'scale' in twogroups (healthy and disease groups).Please see my updated question for more explanations.

Comment: Your reviewer is very confused.  Power is a useful question *only* when you are contemplating obtaining more samples.  For the purpose of assessing the evidence you have, it is irrelevant.

Comment: Great, thanks. Can you elaborate please on 'much more important issues' you mentioned in your comment in above?

Comment: Most are moot based on your previous clarification: I was referring to the need to respect paired data, rather than analyze them separately, and to accommodate missing values appropriately.  Despite the appearance of "NaN" in your data display, you have no missing values: you only have two independent datasets of different sizes.  Perhaps what matters most now is your experimental protocol: when you designed this experiment, what method(s) did you nominate for testing your hypothesis and what result(s) did they give?

Comment: good point. It was an observational pilot study with 60 subjects ('a feasibility study of a new home kit for self monitoring'), they used a home based kit to measure a level of a certain biomarker. It is not a proper randomised clinical study. And due to the pilot nature of this study, we haven't planned initially about hypothesis testing. But now, when we've collected the data, it seems interesting to come up with a new threshold based on the collected data.

Comment: Could you explain how 60 subjects yielded only 43 results?  And if it's not "proper randomized," it will be of great importance to know how the 60 subjects were split into the two groups.  It is especially important that you are testing a hypothesis that was suggested by the data: this raises all kinds of warning flags.  Perhaps you should be content with using the data as intended: namely, to explore the situation and suggest hypotheses for follow-up tests. *Then* a power analysis would be useful for designing those followups.

Comment: I may potentially be aware of certain flaws and will highly appreciate any comments. The data and how we got only 43 out of 60. The disease has two recurrent states: active and remission. In an active (remission) state, the value of a biomarker is increased (decreed). The true diagnosis for active/remission was performed by a clinician in a clinic, while the biomarker test has been performed at home. These two assessments were constrained to be within 1 day: for example:

Comment: if a clinician has checked a patient on Monday morning, then until Wednesday morning, the patient had to perform the home measurement. If not, this measurement was not recorded. So some patients missed the 'window' and thus were excluded. So basically, the group assignment was based on a clinical ('ground truth') judgment. I may foresee your further questions and being not happy with the design, however, the aim was to find and potentially estimate association between the biomarker level and the ground truth state. Does it make sense?